# WP7 Screen Shot Requirements

Tags: windows-phone-7

Microsoft declined to submit my application because I took a screen shot of the game which included the actual emulator.

Looking at [this](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/96106/574002.aspx) answer, the person says that I should us the snipping tool when I have made the phone emulator at 100%. And indeed, the snipping tools spits out an image of that screen at exactly 480x800 which is exactly what Microsoft wants. However, whenever I use the snipping tool, there is still the top black border of the WP7 remaining. I've looked at a few images on the Marketplace and other applications have it as well...I think. Some don't. Can anyone advice me on this please? How I can avoid getting penalised...again.

Will this suffice?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you update to the Windows Phone 7.1 SDK and Emulator, the new emulator has a built-in screenshot function to take screenshots without these issues.

[image: emulator screenshot taking utility]

I have never had my app rejected due to a screenshot taken from the emulator, I can't say you wont have issues, but assuming everything else in your screenshot checks out; the images from the emulator are the correct size and should be approved.

Comment: I already have 7.1 SDK. I just used that tool built within the Emulator but it STILL shows the black border. Will this be okay?

Comment: @Subby I'm not sure what black border you're talking about... Can you upload your screenshot as part of your post so we can take a look and try to diagnose what it is?

Comment: Please check my original post above. I have added an image. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @subby Does the border show up in the emulator? Does the border show up when you run your app on a real device? Can you upload the file that gets output when you click "save" from the emulator tool?

Comment: Whilst I am looking at the application in debug mode, That border, to me, is just the Top Bar for the battery signal and the carrier signal etc. So why is it still part of the Screen shot? The output file is exactly like the one shown in my post

Comment: The black bar in the image you posted seems to big to be just for that part of the OS; however, I've never had any problems submitting screenshots generated form the emulator. That said, it looks like you've got an XNA game, maybe you are not setting it to fullscreen, so you get a larger area not used?

Comment: Hi Nate. It's not XNA, it's Silverlight. The black bar image is BIG because it's in Landscape mode and it's bigger than the black border I get from portrait. Look at this here http://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/apps/fd91ae01-bbcd-4e04-b782-998ff14f41b3, this person has the same thing as I have

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12927/discussion-between-subby-and-nate)

Comment: You can collapse the SystemTray for the page by doing: shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False" within the markup for the Page